# Response entity in Spring MVC 3.1.1

Tags: spring-mvc

I have upgraded Spring from 3.0.5 to 3.1.1 and stumbled upon a curious issue. Following code worked fine in the previous version:

```
@RequestMapping("/getPeople")
public Object getPeople()
    {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders(); responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
        return new ResponseEntity("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But with the latest version I'm getting a 404 error. To resolve this I have to mention the return type as ResponseEntity in the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/getPeople")
    public ResponseEntity getPeople()
        {
            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders(); responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
            return new ResponseEntity("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Is this an acceptable workaround or I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: Maybe it will help:  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-httpentity

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. The @ResponseBody annotation is similar to @RequestBody. This annotation can be put on a method and indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name).

```
@RequestMapping("/getPeople")
@ResponseBody
public Object getPeople()
    {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();  
        responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
        return new ResponseEntity("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Returning responseEntity gives more flexibility and doesn't require @ResponseBody annotation.